# typecast GzipStream to MemoryStream

Tags: powershell

I need to write Gzip decompressed output to file (in binary).
Here is the powershell code i'm currently using:

```
$out = [IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$gzip = [IO.Compression.GzipStream]::new($in,
[IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$gzip.CopyTo($out)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('out.bin', $out.ToArray())
```

I want to make this code shorter, one-liner. So is there any way i can typecast `IO.Compression.GzipStream` to `IO.MemoryStream` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't typecase `GzipStream` to `MemoryStream` but you can decompress to a file directly, without decompressing the whole input to memory first.

```sh
$out = [IO.File]::Create("$PWD\out.bin")
$gzip = [IO.Compression.GzipStream]::new( $in, [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress )
$gzip.CopyTo( $out )
$out.Dispose()  # Close output file
```

Comment: Where did $in come from? Should that be $out?

Comment: @DougMaurer You have to ask OP. `$in` is the source of GZIP-compressed data, so it shouldn't be `$out`.

Comment: @DougMaurer The documentation of the `stream` parameter of the `GzipStream` ctor is incorrect. Decompressed data isn't written to the given stream. The sample code `DecompressFile()` shows the right usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-gzipstream-ctor(system-io-stream-system-io-compression-compressionmode)

Comment: Ahh ok I didn’t see it in op at first. Thanks for replying and the extra info.

Comment: @DougMaurer normally it will be a `MemoryStream` or `FileStream` and yes I agree with zett42, the parameter description on the docs is incorrect in the "decompressing" context but is correct in the "compressing" context. If you want to experiment with Gzip I have some functions [here](https://github.com/santysq/PS-GZip)